# Angularjs inside <style> tag

Tags: angularjs

I'm building some kind of template design tool with angularjs. Everything works fine except this small issue.

I use [[ and ]] as start and end symbols;

```
function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
}
```

In controller i have something like

```
$scope.style.title_color = '#ff0000';
```

and when I generate preview like this

```
<h1 class="title" style="color:[[style.title_color]];">Preview Title</h1>
```

everything works fine. But I need something like

```
<style>
h1.title { color: [[style.title_color]] }
</style>
<h1 class="title">
    Preview Title
</h1>
```

It doesn't work..

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be an issue of scoping.  Is the `<style>` tag inside the same controller scope as `$scope.style.title_color`?

EDIT:
I don't believe Angular works on Style tags.  You should use ng-style instead.

So your `$scope` variable looks like this: `$scope.style.title_color = '#ff0000';` and your DOM element looks like this: `<h1 ng-style="{color: style.title_color}">hello</h1>`

Comment: No.. its not scoping issue. If I change style to div I can see correct plain output. I'll try to give an example somewhere later

Comment: check my edits, i dont think trying to make a style tag dynamic in the first place is the way to go

Comment: I didn't thought I can apply more than one property with ng-style. Now I'll use something like

   <h1 ng-style="style.title">hello</h1>

and in controller

    $scope.style.title = {
        background: 'red',
        color: 'blue'
    }

The problem was that I need to apply many properties to many many tags, so DOM looks terrible.. Thats why I needed "dynamic CSS". Now the problem is solved. Thanks!